# Animate {"Top"} how to stop scrolling div on top position being 0 px - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Trying to create a scrolling div. Wanted to stop  `(thescrollingdiv)`    div once it has reached a particular top position and scrolled all the way to the bottom and not overshoot the parent div into infinity scrolling zone.   `thescrollingdiv` does not have any height specified but its parent div does.Thanks.

`$('#div a).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#thescrollingdiv').stop(true,true).animate({ "top": '-=100px'}, 500)`

Comment: `$('#div a)` should be `$('#div a')` (won't fix your problem tho)

Comment: Sorry typo it is indeed $('#div a')

Answer (score 0):

ScrollTop tells you where you are at. Check the existing top against scrolltop and work the math to set your limits.

```
var scrollTop = $('#thescrollingdiv').scrollTop();
var newTop = parseFloat($('#thescrollingdiv').css('top')) - 100;

if (scrollTop < 0) {
  newTop = 0;
}

$('#thescrollingdiv').stop(true,true).animate({ "top": newTop}, 500)
```

#### UPDATE

Something like this.

```
var topLimit = 0;
var bottomLimit = 800;

var containerTop = parseFloat($('container').css('top'));
var containerBottom = parseFloat($('container').css('height')) + containerTop;

var destination = containerTop - 100;

// compensate for going too far up
destination = (destination < 0) ? 0 : destination;

// compensate for going too far up
destination = (containerBottom > bottomLimit) ? bottomLimit : destination;

// now that you know you are within your custom limits, animate it.
animate(destination);
```

This is almost pseudo code as I don't know what your code looks like, but it gives you an idea. You have to actually DO THE WORK in setting the limits for your 'newTop', before you call animate in the first place.

You can figure it out. Don't be a lazy programmer, though.

Comment: Thank You for your response. But I guess it seems I am not being clear.
Here are two 'clickable links', I click it and it moves 'thescrollingdiv' accordingly. 
ClickUp link moves the div down by 100px which is ok and 
ClickDown link  moves the div up by 100px. 
But both clickable links should stop in either of their respective direction and not scroll further than the content. 

Thanks

Comment: That's exactly my point. I would have to see all of your code to give you exxxaaacccttt direction, but in order to do this, you have to play around with: a. the height of the div that is scrolling, b. the 'top' location of the div, c. the height of the outside container.  There isn't some easy peasy 1 liner jquery command that is going to deal with those details for you. But the above are the tools. I've had to do this type of thing several times.